# Error converting clipboard image

Tags: wpf

Using WPF 4.5

```
private Bitmap BitmapFromSource(BitmapSource bitmapsource)
{
    Bitmap bitmap;
    using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            BitmapEncoder enc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
            enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapsource));
            enc.Save(outStream);
            bitmap = new Bitmap(outStream);
        }
        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

and then later:

```
if (Clipboard.ContainsImage())
{
    var bitmapSouce = Clipboard.GetImage();
    var bitmap = BitmapFromSource(bitmapSouce);
    var tmp = Path.GetTempFileName();
    bitmap.Save(tmp, ImageFormat.Png);
    ...
```

bitmap.Save() throws an ExternalException, "A generic error in GDI+"

Is it really so hard to save a clipboard image to disk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not necessary to create a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` (which is WinForms) from a WPF `BitmapSource` just for saving it.

You could as well directly save to a FileStream:

```
private void SaveBitmap(BitmapSource bitmapSource, string fileName)
{
    var enc = new PngBitmapEncoder();
    enc.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));

    using (var outStream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        enc.Save(outStream);
    }
}

...

var bitmapSource = Clipboard.GetImage();
var tmp = Path.GetTempFileName();
SaveBitmap(bitmapSource, tmp);
```